# Queries avançadas com o "pouchdb-find"

Tags: pouchdb

Como fazer uma pesquisa *contendo* utilizando o pouchdb-find?
O que tenho até agora é isso mas não funciona como o esperado.

```
db.find(selector: {title: "%" + $scope.pesquisa + "%"})
```

É possível fazer com o *emit*? Como ficaria?

Comment: "Não funciona como o esperado" = *não funciona com um `LIKE` de SQL*?

Comment: Isso mesmo, deveria ser equivalente a um `LIKE`. Achei um jeito aqui passando um *callback* para o `db.query` mas ainda preciso testar.